# How to get sulfate reducing bacteria?

Tags: bacteriology

How can I find and get sulfate-reducing bacteria? Where and how can I store them for a long time?

Comment: What are your plans?

Comment: The plan is to put it into an apple size capsule that would be sent to Mars. So basically the bacteria should stay alive during the travel period and after impact to the planet.

Comment: Another point is to make them to be the only of microorganism species in the substance. Because I do not want something oxygen consuming to get there before some source.

Comment: The oxygen might be needed for algae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sulfate-reducing bacteria are everywhere, one spoon of soil contains several different species of them. The problem is how to isolate them from the other bacteria.
[This old paper](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiV94-LjbLPAhWG2RoKHW1dBX0QFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmic.microbiologyresearch.org%2Fcontent%2Fjournal%2Fmicro%2F10.1099%2F00221287-3-1-46%3Fcrawler%3Dtrue%26mimetype%3Dapplication%2Fpdf&usg=AFQjCNFyZ-1mz5FZgBz3_2dUdsN_Unn_iw&sig2=Fx-I4P8a7R-2D3n9K5TjWg) explains how to do it, I am sure there are newer techniques to do the same, it's up to you to dig into the literature to find the one you prefer if you want to isolate them by yourself.

Otherwise, [just buy it from a collection](https://www.lgcstandards-atcc.org/products/all/35288.aspx?geo_country=nl#generalinformation).

Comment: Old paper page is not available. Do you have it in webarchive?

Comment: Wired, the link was active few hours ago.. I have uploaded the file here http://www.filedropper.com/mic-3-1-46

Comment: I have updated the link of "This old paper" now it should work.